# No ingresan datos en ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

Estoy desarrollando un webapp de administración de recursos humanos en un modulo de agregar personas en asp.net y sql server pero al momento de generar una carga de usuarios mediante un formulario estos no se agregan en la base de datos y no generan ninguna actividad cuando presiono el boton guardar datos personal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen del formulario de carga de archivos

String de Conexion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcion de Agregar Personal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo Funciones de la pagina del webforms
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No está clara tu pregunta. Por qué no guarda? Hay multitiud de razones por las cuales no se guardaría un registro en una base de datos. Creo que tendrás que ser más específico. Hay excepciones? Ya corriste el SQL profiler? Cuál es el resultado de `p.guardar()`? En la pestaña `output`, sale algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Tampoco entrega ninguna cosa, en cambio cuando hago ingresos de RUT me lo bloquea si coloco un valor por ejemplo 10.220.330-0 me entrega errores nada mas que eso

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: El código va como texto. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes.